# Jquery callback function working only with debugger

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Following is my jquery function :

```
function logIn() {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("LogIn", "Login")',
        success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            if (result == "Ok") {
                debugger;
                var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
                location.href = url;
            }
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
}
```

And following is my LogIn function in controller :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        int userId = userService.LoginUser("a@b.com", "abc");
       // return View("../Home/Index");
        return Json("Ok");
    }
```

It works fine if I debug the jquery function. However if I remove debuggers, control does not come in success portion of function. I am not sure what is wrong here.
I also tried replacing jquery function as follows but it is also not working :

```
function logIn() {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("LogIn", "Login")'
        }).done(function (data) {
            debugger;
            var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
            location.href = url;
        })
          .fail(function () { alert("error"); })
          .always(function () { alert("complete"); });
    }
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Does it break if you remove the server-side debugger? Is your MVC application running on IIS on Cassini?

Comment: You're cheching for the string `Ok`, but the returned result is really JSON, so that will fail ?

Comment: It is running on IIS. I didn't get your first query.

Comment: @adeneo I have mentioned dataType: "json" in jquery function. I guess it will compare correctly.

Comment: In some circumstances breakpoint for the jquery code will not be hit in VS. Try putting breakpoint for the compiled version of file. Or just use alert in success callback to check if control is actually coming or not..

Comment: setting the dataType to JSON just means you're expecting the returned data to be JSON, and if it's not, the ajax call will fail, and if it is, the check for a string will fail. Either way you'll fail.

Comment: @adeneo Then what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Check the right property of the returned object instead of the string `Ok`, as it will return an object and not a string. Just console log `result` to see what it is ?

Comment: @adeneo : But if that was the case it won't have worked on debugging. Isn't it ?

Comment: Fire FireBug or other debugging tool and see whats happening: error console, step through with debugger...

Answer (score 0):

It Happens when your server is not returning the proper JOSN.

first try

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("LogIn", "Login")',
    success: function (result) {
       console.log(result);
    },

});
```

And check if output is a proper JSON or not,

you can also try manually parsing the JSON using `$.parseJSON()`

hope it helps.